# how to modify a textview from diffent class in different thread - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity

First of all, I'm not an expert, so I hope to explain in the right way and hopefully to get replies that are not too complex.

I have the main activity that run in a new thread. let's call it "thread-1", some operations (exchane data between server and client .
thread-1 remains alive forever.

The main activity after some time open a new activity, let's call it activity-2
activity-2 has a textView, let's call it textView-2.

After some time the running thread-1 invoking a static method, inside a Java class, that has to modify in real time textView.

How can I do that?
Thank you very much in advance.
Fausto

Comment: Bro No Clarity in Question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider posting some code so we can help you more clearly. Also show us where exactly you get problems. In general and without having looked at your code: it's generally discouraged to modify instance variables through static methods. It is possible through the so called Singleton design pattern, but the way to go would be to have thread-1 obtain a reference to the textView by other means (i.e. a constructor or a setter) and then manipulate that one.

Comment: Ciao, thank you for your reply. I have to write the code because I don't know how to do it. Let me say that I can try to do what you suggest " to have thread-1 obtain a reference to the textView by other means (i.e. a constructor or a setter) and then manipulate that one"

Comment: Ciao, thank you for your reply. I didn't write the code because I don't know what is the code to get my target. I didn't understand very well your suggestion:  it's clear that it is better to not use a static method, but it is the alternative " to have thread-1 obtain a reference to the textView by other means (i.e. a constructor or a setter) and then manipulate that one"? Can you make an example? Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of the story, I solved in this way:

- Activity-2 launch a listener thread (by a while cycle)
- Thread-1 of activity-1, when it wants to change a TextView of activity-2 , sends a message to the listener (modifying the value of a static var of the listener)

  - the listener receive the message and send it to Activity-2 (by an Handle), then finally it changes the TextView
  - I inserted a control that exit from the while cycle when not needed anymore

I hope can helps someone else...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (and shouldn't) do what you describe.  The first `Activity` is no longer in a running state once the second `Activity` is started.  Their lifecycle callbacks are called on the same thread: the main thread of your `Activity`.  Your first `Activity` should have no direct ties like this to your second `Activity`.  If you do need a secondary background thread, you must start it manually or use something else like `AsyncTask` or even RxJava's observers.  But, you cannot directly change the state of `View` objects while on other threads, they can only be altered when running in the context of your main thread.

Comment: Ciao, note that the first activity runs a new thread (different from main), and that thread continues to be running also when the second activity is started. I'm sure of that because this part is already implemented. To be honest I'm not enough expert and I didn't understand the second part of your answer "If you do need a secondary background thread, you must start it manually or use something else ....."

Comment: You'll want to be very careful starting threads and allowing them to continue to run after an `Activity` has been paused or stopped.  You could run into problems with memory leaks as well as invalid state exceptions if your thread tries to directly manipulate the `Activity` or hold a strong reference to it.  Getting back to your main question: you cannot change a `View` from outside of the main thread.  You can read its state or data from it, but you cannot alter it.